# Нужно ли указывать final для всех переменных которые не изменяются?

Tags: java, cleancode

В книгах о Java написано, что если переменная не будет изменятся, то нужно указывать модификатор final. Но получается, что тогда этот модификатор нужно указывать почти всегда. Я просматривал репозитории с кодом на Java и заметил, что этот модификатор используется не так часто.

Ниже пример моей [программы](https://github.com/rabestro/sololearn-challenges/blob/master/hovercraft/Hovercraft.java), здесь 100% переменных отмечены модификатором final.

Является ли это правильным? 
Соответствует ли это принципам чистого кода?
Используете ли вы сами подобный подход? 
Если нет, то почему?

Пример (2)

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NoNumerals
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final var phrase = input.nextLine();
        final String[] numbers = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};
        final var updatedPhrase = new StringBuilder();

        for (final var word : phrase.split(" ")) {
            try {
                final int number = Integer.parseInt(word);
                if (number >= 0 && number <= 10) {
                        updatedPhrase.append(numbers[number]);
                } else {
                        updatedPhrase.append(word);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                updatedPhrase.append(word);
            } finally {
                updatedPhrase.append(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print(updatedPhrase);
    }
}
```

Пример (1)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hovercraft
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int sales = input.nextInt();

        final long hovercraftMonth = 10;
        final long hovercraftCosts = 2_000_000;
        final long hovercraftPrice = 3_000_000;
        final long insuranceMonth = 1_000_000;
        final long spentMonth = hovercraftMonth * hovercraftCosts + insuranceMonth;
        final long incomeMonth = sales * hovercraftPrice;

        if (incomeMonth > spentMonth) {
            System.out.print("Profit");
        } else if (incomeMonth < spentMonth) {
            System.out.print("Loss");
        } else {
            System.out.print("Broke Even");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Совсем не почти всегда. Неизменяемых переменных обычно не так много, как вам кажется. Не все программы такие короткие и простые, как ваша.

Comment: имхо внутри метода пользы от final куда меньше, чем у полей класса

Comment: вы используете что-то реактивное либо функциональное? если нет, то попробуйте и вопросов на этот счет станет меньше.

Comment: @Эникейщик, вообще, после Kotlin кажется, что, наоборот, изменяемых переменных почти не бывает.

Comment: По опыту, что у меня есть, неизменяемых переменных большинство. Конечно, опыта у меня пока не так много, поэтому и задаю такие вопросы.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> этот модификатор нужно указывать почти всегда.

Зависит от стиля, принятого в компании. Почти всегда `final` указывают у статичных
констант, или при работе с несколькими потоками. Видел стиль, когда `final` всегда указывался в параметрах функции, но редко.

> Является ли это правильным?

Это и облегчит, и усложнит чтение кода. Лучше использовать `final`, если между объявлением поля и его последним использованием достаточно много строк. Если же строк несколько, то можно не указывать, т.к. это увеличит длину строки.

В вашем случае я бы оставил `final` у 1-х двух строк в 1-м примере, и у 1-х четырёх -- во 2-м примере.

> Соответствует ли это принципам чистого кода?

Использование `final` для статичных констант и при работе с потоками -- соответствует. В остальных случаях -- опционально.

> Используете ли вы сами подобный подход?

Я довольно часто указываю `final`, хотя чаще использую функциональные (или мультипарадигменные) языки, где практически нет переменных (есть константы). При работе с JS также предпочитаю `const`, т.к. использование `const` почти не увеличивает длину строки, т.е. не ухудшает читаемость. В Java часто указываю `final` у коллекций, чтоб быть уверенным, что коллекция не будет равна `null`.

**Рекомендации Twitter на английском**: [1](https://github.com/twitter-archive/commons/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/common/styleguide.md#use-final-fields)
[2](https://github.com/twitter-archive/commons/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/common/styleguide.md#favor-immutability)

Попытался перевести:

> Финальные поля полезны, потому что эти поля не могут быть переназначены. Когда дело доходит до проверки безопасности потока, можно будет не переживать хотя бы за изменяемость полей.
>
> В общем случае, изменяемое статическое состояние является признаком плохого дизайна класса.
>
> Изменяемые объекты требуют внимания -- вы должны убедиться, что те, кто может их изменять, не нарушают ожиданий других пользователей объекта, и что их безопасно изменять.

**Из стиля Google**: [1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.7-local-variable-names)

> Локальные переменные не должны быть стилизированы под константы.

**Из требований Oracle** [1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> Любая локальная переменная, используемая, но не объявленная во вложенном классе, должна быть объявленна как `final` или должна быть финальной по факту.

**Схожие вопросы на английском**:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011520/what-does-final-do-if-you-place-it-before-a-variable)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299837/cannot-refer-to-a-non-final-variable-inside-an-inner-class-defined-in-a-differen?rq=1)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279420/does-use-of-final-keyword-in-java-improve-the-performance?rq=1)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504892/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-final-input-parameter-in-method-signature/6504911#6504911)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4162782/5122436)
[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/what-is-the-point-of-final-class-in-java?rq=1)
[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45309847/how-to-auto-fix-checkstyle-warnings-of-finallocalvariable-and-finalparameters-by)

Пока что лень перевести полезные выдержки из них. Возможно, некоторые из ответов несколько субъективны.

Answer (score 6):

Нет, указывать final везде где возможно не нужно. Данный модификатор нужен только для защиты констант, что используются много где в коде и не должны быть случайно изменены. А если какая-то переменная была объявлена в теле небольшой функции, то ты и так менять её не будешь. Модификаторы - это страховка от ошибок программиста. В код они вроде никак не компилируются, однако при компиляции, если нарушено правило модификатора, дают ошибку